# Date format "dd/MM/yyyyy" Asp.Net Core

Tags: .net, datetime, datetime-format

I am working on ASP.NET Core app and I want date format over the project like `dd/MM/yyyy`. What is the best practice for displaying date with format `dd/MM/yyyy` in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 2):

you can format dates like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```